# My buttons and Views do nothing after inflating the layout they are in so avoid null object error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, android-inflate

My Main Activity. This is where all my code is.

```
package com.abhiandroid.tablayoutexample;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FrameLayout simpleFrameLayout;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ImageButton imageRopo;
    Button btn_show;
    InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    AdView adView1,adView2;
    TextView textView;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View firstfrag =getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_first,null);
        View thirdfrag =getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_third,null);




        btn_show = (Button)thirdfrag.findViewById(R.id.bt_show);
        adView1= (AdView)thirdfrag.findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
        adView2= (AdView)thirdfrag.findViewById(R.id.ad_view2);
        imageRopo = (ImageButton)firstfrag.findViewById(R.id.buttonropo);
        textView  = (TextView)firstfrag.findViewById(R.id.testview);



        imageRopo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com"));
                startActivity(intent);

                textView.setText("The button works");

            }
        });


        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-8708219564656739~8048449285");

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("355696115338836").build();
        adView1.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView2.loadAd(adRequest);


        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8708219564656739/2401085524");
        interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("355697115338836").build());


        btn_show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                interstitialAd.show();
            }
        });

        // get the reference of FrameLayout and TabLayout
        simpleFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.simpleFrameLayout);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.simpleTabLayout);
        // Create a new Tab named "First"
        TabLayout.Tab firstTab = tabLayout.newTab();
        firstTab.setText("Apps"); // set the Text for the first Tab
        firstTab.setIcon(R.drawable.app); // set an icon for the
        // first tab
        tabLayout.addTab(firstTab); // add  the tab at in the TabLayout
        // Create a new Tab named "Second"
        TabLayout.Tab secondTab = tabLayout.newTab();
        secondTab.setText("Products"); // set the Text for the second Tab
        secondTab.setIcon(R.drawable.company); // set an icon for the second tab
        tabLayout.addTab(secondTab); // add  the tab  in the TabLayout
        // Create a new Tab named "Third"
        TabLayout.Tab thirdTab = tabLayout.newTab();
        thirdTab.setText("Donate"); // set the Text for the first Tab
        thirdTab.setIcon(R.drawable.donation); // set an icon for the first tab
        tabLayout.addTab(thirdTab); // add  the tab at in the TabLayout


        // perform setOnTabSelectedListener event on TabLayout
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                // get the current selected tab's position and replace the fragment accordingly
                Fragment fragment = null;
                switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        fragment = new FirstFragment();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fragment = new SecondFragment();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        fragment = new ThirdFragment();
                        break;
                }
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                ft.commit();
            }



            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

My activit_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/simpleTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabBackground="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#f00"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#f00"
        app:tabTextColor="#000" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/simpleFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#9C27B0">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The buttons and views are in different fragments hence me having to inflate the layouts they are in.

This is my firstfragment.xml. This is where one of my button and one of my TextView is.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffeadb"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f7c5a8"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".FirstFragment"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Why Choose China when you have the option for Indian?"
            android:textSize="37sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="109dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="208dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="281dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="281dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tiktokl"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Why Choose Chinese when you can choose an Indian Alternative."
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.255"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="114dp"
            android:layout_height="114dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="149dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="149dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="192dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="148dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="148dp"
            android:src="@drawable/red_arrow"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonropo"
            android:layout_width="132dp"
            android:layout_height="118dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="281dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="281dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="183dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:src="@drawable/roposoapplog"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/testview"
            android:layout_width="88dp"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="168dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="168dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="336dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="155dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="155dp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

My ThirdFragement Activity file is very empty.

```
package com.abhiandroid.tablayoutexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {




 
    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }


 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }
 
}
```

Before inflating the layouts, I would get a null object error and after inflating them they no-longer seem to work. They don't do anything. As you can see in my MainActivity.java file I had made is so that when a user clicks a button it redirects them to a website. I even made a TextView that updates itself when the Button is clicked so that I know that the Button is working. I have spent days trying to fix this error and have made no progress. I suspect it is related to some code being wrong while making the fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the logic for your Fragment's views inside your Fragment class.
So, instead of doing the logic for the button in the Activity, do it under the Fragment `onCreateView()`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    imageRopo = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonropo);
    textView  = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.testview);

    imageRopo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ...
    // ... and so on

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this and tell you how it goes.